# Finding and Using Camera found in “Imaging Devices” in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, directshow, aforge, device-manager

I have a camera that I am able to use with older applications built in c/c++ and VB6 (circa 2003). I didn’t write the older code.

The device driver is recognized in Imaging Devices but cannot be updated to Camera in Device Manager.

I can find the camera using Manager request functions.

I am trying to use the camera but DirectShow, Cv2, and AForge will not recognize the device.

I only have the most recent driver and old dll files which cannot be assembled on VS2022.

any help?